# Filtering a nested array and return the array which matches the value for the key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, nested

I'm trying to filter an array which contains arrays of object, based on the id.
I'm able to filter them, but need to clean up the output a bit as it also returns an empty array, since the condition doesn't match for that array.

How do I fix it?

```js
const resKey = 'ABC';
const data = [
  [{
    "user": {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Smith",
    },
    "id": "ABC"
  }],
  [{
    "user": {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Smith",
    },
    "id": "DEF"
  }]
];

const result = data.map(eachArr => eachArr.filter(eachObj => eachObj.id === resKey));
console.log(result);
```

Expected Output:

```
[
  [
    {
      user: {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Smith",
      },
      id: "ABC",
    },
  ],
]
```

Actual Output:

```
[
  [
    {
      user: {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Smith",
      },
      id: "ABC",
    },
  ],
  [],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can again filter out the empty array which doesn't contain an elements (`length` is `0`) using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
.filter((arr) => arr.length);
```

```js
const resKey = "ABC";
const data = [
  [
    {
      user: {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Smith",
      },
      id: "ABC",
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      user: {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Smith",
      },
      id: "DEF",
    },
  ],
];

const result = data
  .map((eachArr) => eachArr.filter((eachObj) => eachObj.id === resKey))
  .filter((arr) => arr.length);
  
console.log(result);
```